# Ionic android app only works on android 7.0+

Tags: android, ionic4

Im working on a project with ionic(v4)+angular+angular material. Im trying to export apk but i have a problem. i tried several emulators for testing. But i got white screen after splash screen on android 4.4, 5.0 and 6.0. But it also works well on android 7, 8, 9.
my config.xml has these line;

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

I have downloaded sdk 19 with android studio. Please help me if you know any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It works well on real devices. Emulators with old android versions doesnt work well with ionic.